# Bubble Sort an array of strings using index

Tags: ruby, bubble-sort

Hello I am thoroughly confused on how to implement bubble sort in an array of strings. I need to write a method in which I swap index 1 and index 2 using an array. For something like swapper(["b", "c", "l"], 0, 1) I want this solution: ["c", "b", "l"]
Here's the code so far:

```
def swapper(arr, idx_1, idx_2)
sorted = false
while != sorted 
sorted = true

(0...arr.length - 1).each do |i|
    #idk how to compare idx_1 and idx_2 to swap            
    sorted = false    
end
```

end

Comment: Do you want code to implement a bubble sort or code for a helper method that simply swaps two elements of an array?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
def swapper(arr, idx_1, idx_2)
    arr[idx_1], arr[idx_2] = arr[idx_2], arr[idx_1]
    return arr
end
```

Comment: I can't believe I had tried that before and did not get the results I wanted because I forgot to return array ! wow thank you so much

Comment: You don't need `return` as that is the last statement executed; `arr` is sufficient and what most Rubyists would write.

Comment: @CarySwoveland agreed! Just wanted to include to be explicit for OP :)